# Grafana, non-standard information in log

Tags: grafana

I got non-standard information in K8s/Grafana log (see grafana-usage-report):

```
{"err":"Post \"https://stats.grafana.org/grafana-usage-report\": dial tcp 34.96.126.106:443: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)", "logger":"metrics", "lvl":"error", "msg":"Failed to send usage stats", "t":"2022-09-30T14:20:48.829643536Z"} 
{"err":"Post \"https://stats.grafana.org/grafana-usage-report\": dial tcp 34.96.126.106:443: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)", "logger": "metrics", "lvl":"error","msg":"Failed to send usage stats", "t":"2022-10-01T14:20:53.032838369Z"} 
{"err":"Post \"https://stats.grafana.org/grafana-usage-report\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)","logger":"metrics","lvl":"error","msg":"Failed to send usage stats", "t":"2022-10-02T14:20:55.4582491Z"} 
{"err":"Post \"https://stats.grafana.org/grafana-usage-report\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)", "logger":"metrics","lvl": "error", "msg":"Failed to send usage stats", "t":"2022-10-03T14:21:00.4734810072"}
```

I checked useful comments under this question and I saw:

- focus on config
- log level
- but it can have relation to Loki

But it is without progress on my side, right now (logs seems fine, debug level also, probably issue with Loki). Did you catch similar issue? How do you block sending these statistics on grafana/loki side?

BTW: Block communication in network level is easy, but I am looking for better/system solution.

Comment: https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-are-trying-to-resolve-stats-grafana-org-even-when-reporting-is-disabled/70470/4

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient.Also have you checked the link shared by @JanGaraj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue based on these a few steps:

- setup higher log detail
- identify invalid content of **grafana.ini** file (based on coding, etc.)
- finally I used `reporting_enabled = false` (it was the key point)